# Memory management with image saved from UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm writing an app in which the user takes a photo of them self, and then goes through a series of views to adjust the image using a navigation controller. This works perfectly fine if the user takes the photo with the front camera (set as default on devices that support it), but when I repeat the process I get about half way through and it crashes after throwing a memory warning.

After profiling in Instruments I see that my apps memory footprint holds at about 20-25 MB when using the lower resolution front camera image, but when using the back camera every view change adds another 33 MB or so until it crashes at about 350 MB (on a 4S)

Below is the code I'm using to handle saving the photo to the documents directory, and then reading that file location to set the image to a `UIImageView`. The "read" portion of this code is recycled through several view controllers (viewDidLoad) to set the image I saved as the background image in each view as I go.

I have removed all my image modification code to strip this down to the bear minimum attempting to isolate the problem, and I can't seem to find it. As it stands right now, all the app does is take a photo in the first view and then use that photo as the background image for about 10 more views, allocating as the user navigates through the view stack.

Now obviously the higher resolution photos would use more memory, but what I don't understand is that why the low resolution photos don't seem to be using more and more memory as I go, whereas the high resolution photos continuously use more and more until a crash.

How I am saving and reading the image:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];    
    jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpeg"];
    [jpgData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];    

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [disableNextButton setEnabled:YES];

    jpgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:jpgData];
    [imageView setImage:image2];
}
```

Now I know that I could try scaling the image before I save it, which I plan on looking into next, but I don't see why this doesn't work as is. Maybe I was falsely under the impression that ARC automatically deallocated views and their subviews when they leave the top of the stack.

Can anyone shed some light on why I'm stock piling my devices memory? (Hopefully something simple I'm completely overlooking) Did I somehow manage to throw ARC out the window?

**EDIT:** How I call for the image in my other views

```
- (void)loadBackground
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpeg"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [backgroundImageView setImage:image];

}
```

How navigation between my view controllers is established:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

What my basic declarations look like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface PhotoPickerViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    NSData *jpgData;
    NSString *filePath;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *disableNextButton;
}


@end
```

If relevant, how I call up my image picker:

```
- (void)callCameraPicker
{


    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Camera is available and ready");

        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

        NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]; for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) 
        {
            if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) 
            {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;


            }
        }


        imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    }


    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Camera is not available");
        UIAlertView *cameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                              message:@"Your device doesn't seem to have a camera!" 
                                                             delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cameraAlert show];

    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:** I logged viewDidUnload, and it was in fact not being called so I'm now calling `loadBackground` in `viewWillAppear` and making my `backgroundImageView` nil in `viewDidDisappear`. I expected this to help but it made no difference.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self loadBackground];
}


- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"ViewDidDisappear");
    backgroundImageView = nil;
}
```

Comment: you should not use `imageWithData` as you can use `imageWithContentsOfFile`. `imageWithData` can't be cached so you will create a new byte-buffer for every image.

Comment: May I ask why you are creating image2 as a UIImage object from the data, when you have that as a UIImage already from your UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage key in the info dictionary ?

Also you can nill the image and jpgdata once you complete all tasks to free the memory...

Comment: @JonathanCichon Unfortunately neither `imageWithData` or `imageWithContentsOfFile` cache the data.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't create `image2` by loading it back from file - just do `[imageView setImage:image]`. You're doubling your memory requirements by loading it up a second time. That only explains so much though - I think we need to see some example code of your 10 views in the navigation stack to see what you are doing in there - it sounds like you are loading up the image in each one and somehow preventing iOS from freeing up the ones lower in the nav stack.

Comment: Good point, I've made the corrections to that bit of code, and there really isn't much to show. The code I listed above (the reading part) is recycled in the viewDidLoad methods of my other view controllers, which are simply linked to view controllers in a storyboard set up to push from one to another.

Comment: And my image views are made nil viewDidUnload.

Comment: I've made an edit elaborating on this^^

Comment: viewDidUnload won't get called unless iOS chooses to unload that view this should happen under low memory conditions but for some reason this sometimes doesn't happen on iOS 5.x devices. Could you put a NSLog in to see if this is being called for your other views? Currently you are loading the image from disk in `loadBackground`, and if the previous ones don't get unloaded then you are holding multiple images in memory at once. And iPhone 4S images are big! You could also try doing [imageView setImage:nil] in viewDidDisappear, and load it back up in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @RobB I had high hopes about this suggestion but it didn't help. See edit 3. This problem seems to just keep getting stranger.

Comment: @Rob B no they don't cache in memory, but i assume `imageWithContentsOfFile` can be purged, at least `initWithContentsOfFile` can be, this can reduce memory-foodprint by a lot. 'cache' was the wrong term.

Comment: @MDT You should nil out backgroundImageView.image, not backgroundImageView. The UIImageView will still be referenced by the view (which is still loaded), so it won't release the image. You want the UIImageView to be available but to not be referencing your large image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relationship between `UIImage` and `UIImageView` is not necessarily intuitive for everyone.

`UIImage` is a high level representation of your image data - alone, it does nothing in terms of displaying the data.

`UIImageView` works with `UIImage` to allow you to display an image.

There is no reason why multiple instances of `UIImageView` cannot display the same `UIImage`.  This is nice and efficient, because there is only one in-memory representation of the image data, being shared by multiple views.

What you seem to be doing is creating a new `UIImage` for each one of your views, by loading it from disk.  So this is a poor general design in two respects: instantiating what is effectively the same `UIImage` over and over again, and re-loading the same image data from disk repeatedly.

Your memory problem is really a separate issue, where you are not properly releasing the image data you keep loading into `UIImage` objects and `UIImageViews`.

In theory, you should be able to take the very first `UIImage` you're getting from `UIImagePickerController` and simply pass that reference around to your views, without reloading from disk.

If you need to be saving and reloading from disk because of higher level functional requirements (e.g. because the image is being changed by the user and you want to keep saving it), you'll need to be sure you are fully tearing down the previous `UIView`, by removing it from the it's view hierarchy.  It is helpful to setup a breakpoint in the dealloc method for the view to confirm it is being removed and dealloced, and make sure you set any `iVar` references to sub-views (it appears your `backgroundImageView` is an iVar) are set to nil.  If you are not properly tearing down that `backgroundImageView`, it is continuing to hold a reference to the `UIImage` you set to it's image property.

Comment: I'm wondering something about this. Does this mean it is more efficient to store a bunch of UIImage's in an array in one class(lets say a singleton one) and setting myImageView.image = [singletonarray objectAtIndex:k]; throughout the app, compared to calling myImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:someNSStringWithTheImageName]; ? Do these two options differ a lot? @Rob Reuss

Comment: Obviously, it's best if you're only having in memory only images that you are displaying (or about to display because they're on a scrollview).  If your app provides access to a collection of images that the user might randomly decide to display, and you want to maximize the performance for the user by pre-loading them or retaining them after they are loaded, NSCache can be a great solution.  It functions like an NSMutableDictionary, but will dynamically remove objects if there are memory constraints.  You can store your images to NSCache using their file path as a key.  It's cool.

Comment: @0x7fffffff - Interested on your route to resolve this. Did you decide to use the reference from the original UIImage and pass this onto the other VCs, or did you follow the second method of ensuring the view is correctly removed/dealloc'ed?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are *curious* about the code you posted:

1. None of your view-callback implementations call `super`. **That’s bad!** Make extra sure that you are calling super in `viewDidUnload` and (if you implemented it) `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.
2. Make sure you implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in a meaningful way!
3. You **really** should not be re-creating that image over and over again! I assume you are not editing the actual image because you use JPEG compression on it which — even at 100% quality — will deteriorate your image with every save…
4. Check your implementation of `viewDidUnload` make sure to set every of your IBOutlets to `nil`.

ARC is not Pixie Dust™! It just saves you a bit of typing, it does **not** free you from designing and maintaining your object graphs!

From your question, I see at the very least these graphs that refer to your image:

```
image 1 <- image-view 1 <- view-controller 1 <- navigation-controller <- key window <- application

image 1 <- image-view 1 <- view 1 <- view-controller 1 <- navigation-controller <- key window <- application
```

This is repeated for every view-controller with an index shift on the view-controller, view, image view and image. While you have to have separate views, image-views for your view-controllers, I cannot think of a reason why you would want several copies of the same image.

So the first axe on your memory consumption clearly is to no longer create all those copies of the same image data — I’d estimate that this will get you half of the low-hanging memory savings.

The next thing is that ARC can only free the memory consumed by your objects if it is no longer referenced.

Memory wise, views are not exactly lightweight objects and when you build up a deep navigation stack you end up with gobs of them.

So you need to axe any unneeded strong references to those views, as well.

The *level*, at which this has to happen is the view-controller. The latest *time* at which this *should* happen is in the view-controller’s implementation of `viewDidUnload`.

### Why the view-controller?

From what you described, the image itself is only referenced by the UIImageView — this is a bad choice, IMHO, but I digress…
`UIViewController` is designed to “know”, when its view is needed and when it’s safe to dispose of it — that’s why it implements `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `viewDidUnload`:

If the memory pressure gets to high and the view-controller’s view is not “on screen” the root implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWorning` will let go of its view and call `viewDidUnload` upon itself, afterwards.

This is why you **must** call through to `super` in your implementations of *both of those methods.*

In addition, this is why if you have strong IBOutlets that refer to subviews of the view-controller’s view, you **must** nil them in `viewDidUnload` or the system cannot reclaim the memory they occupy.

At its heart `UIViewController` is a big-ass finite state-machine. All of those “something-will/did-whatever” callbacks are used to transition between those states and most of the default implementations do some very important book-keeping to keep all that state in order.

If you are not invoking them in your overrides, you˚ll end up in inconsistent states and bad things — like this out of memory crasher — happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just create separate folder and save your Capture images in it. After your successful operation clear that folder data(or)folder.using the nsfilemager.